# WP Site's Live Robots.txt Differs from local Robots.txt accessed by SFTP

Tags: wordpress, web-crawler, seo, robots.txt, wpengine

I have a Wordpress site, hosted on WPEngine, that serves as a CMS for our website through an endpoint.

On the Wordpress site, I have installed YoastSEO plugin, and have edited the robots.txt file to the following:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /nogooglebot/

User-agent: *
Allow: /

Sitemap: https://[my-site].wpengine.com/sitemap_index.xml
```

however, when I navigate to [my-site].com/robots.txt (on incognito, or via a robots.txt tester), it shows up as:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

In order to ensure the changes were being applied from the Yoast plugin,  I accessed the Wordpress files via SFTP, and the robots.txt in the root directory matches the one Yoast presents on the dashboard,

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /nogooglebot/

User-agent: *
Allow: /

Sitemap: https://[my-site].wpengine.com/sitemap_index.xml
```

I've cleared the WP cache and my local cache multiple times, but the live robots.txt still is incorrect.

Why would there be a difference here? How can I force the WP environment to use the robots.txt I've edited instead of the one it's providing?

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this myself, it is due to the following:

> By default, WP Engine restricts the traffic of search engines to any
> site using the environment.wpengine.com domain. This means search
> engines will not be able to visit sites which are not currently in
> production using a custom domain.

As documented here: https://wpengine.com/support/read-use-robots-txt/

In my case, I implemented CloudFront CDN with .wpengine.com as the origin. I talked to WPEngine support and they changed a setting to allow crawling on that domain.